# Binding to Active Directory using django-auth-ldap

Tags: django, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create user login authentication in my django app via Active Directory using **django-auth-ldap**. The problem is that I cannot bind to the AD using **username** (which is *sAMAccountName* LDAP equivalent). Part of my settings.py below:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
]

AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = False
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = False
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://ip_address:389'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ''
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ''
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('DC=example,DC=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)')
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
}
```

**Console log:**

```
ERROR search_s('DC=example,DC=com', 2, '(sAMAccountName=user)') raised OPERATIONS_ERROR({'desc': 'Operations error', 'info': '00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece'})
DEBUG search_s('DC=example,DC=com', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 0 objects:
DEBUG Authentication failed for user: failed to map the username to a DN.
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You have an answer, accept and upvote if it helps or leave a comment and develop or edit your question if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous read access is not enabled by default. To perform the search operation, populate AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN and AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD with a valid account. I generally create dedicated "system" accounts (i.e. not a real person's account because your authentication starts failing every time the user changes their password).

Comment: Great! Works perfectly! Thanks a lot! In other hand, u said about dedicated "system" accounts - you mean to create one special account which will be used only for binding to AD via LDAP?

Comment: Yup, a regular user account but created specifically for binding to AD via LDAP. I work for a large corp, so I set up a special account for each app (even three apps supported by the same group, I have three IDs because who knows what will happen in future reorgs). A single account could be shared -- just makes coordinating periodic password changes more challenging. Since the account will only ever auth against a domain controller, I've got a batch that ensures userWorkstations on the LDAP bind accounts are set to the list of domain controllers for the org too.